# Проблема с CRUD запросами в API

Tags: api, url, django-rest-framework, router

Изначально был сделан небольшой учебный сайт, теперь к нему прикручиваю учебный же API. Работаю, как, наверное, и большинство, с вьюсетами и роутерами. Столкнулся с двумя проблемами, одна с маршрутизацией, вторая с вьюсетом. Первую описываю ниже. Возможно, вторая решится сама, когда будет решена первая. Если не решится - напишу отдельный вопрос.

Суть в том, что на учебном сайте есть возможность писать посты и есть возможность писать комментарии к ним. Сейчас при помощи API-запроса мне нужно получить все комментарии конкретного поста. Маршрут в роутере выглядит вот так:
`router.register('api/v1/posts/<int:post_id>/comments', CommentViewSet, basename='comment')`

Запрос в Postman выглядит так: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/posts/2/comments/

То есть, в `<int:post_id>` я передаю 2. Результат - появляется ошибка, в которой Джанго говорит, что перепробовал все возможные адреса и ни один не подходит к тому, который в запросе. Подскажите, что именно не так здесь. Скрин приложил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решено путем использования регулярного выражения вида `router.register(r'api/v1/posts/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comments', CommentViewSet, basename='comment')`